# Formatting info in table created by while cycle

Tags: php, html-table, hidden

In my pages (I rent a programmer who made this... and I'm trying fix everything  done badly...) I have problem with part of signpost. Its part of code which make different list depending on steps before, and when you move with your mouse over one of the item of this list, its "shows" some text on the left side...

He used table I  try to change it from table to `<li>` but nothing changed...

Problem is that every text is begin from a row of marked item of the list and I would like to start from first row of the table ....

Here is part of code...

```
while ($rowshowvarianty = mysqli_fetch_array($resultshowvarianty)){

echo '<tr id="line" class="line">
<td style="   line-height: 25px; ">
<span style="width:250px;  background: #e74c3c;color: white;border-radius: 50%;
padding: 0px 7.5px;">?</span>
</td>
<td style="    font-size: 13px;    width: 100%; ">
<a style="text-decoration: none;    color: #232323;"  
 href="?step=3&cil='.$_GET['cil'].'
 plan='.$rowshowvarianty['id'].'">'.$rowshowvarianty['nazev'].'</a>
</td>';

echo '<td style="width:400px;      top: 0px;     margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; ">
<span class="hiddentooltip" id="'.$rowshowvarianty['id'].'">'
.$rowshowvarianty['pruvodce'].'</span>
</td></tr>';
}

CSS:

.line:hover .hiddentooltip,
.line:hover ~ .hiddentooltip{
    left: -400px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;    display: block;
}.line td:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 350px !important;
    width: 30% !important;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.hiddentooltip{
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
```

[image: HERE IS THE PHOTO]

Comment: Your question doesn't clearly define what you wish to do. If you want to change it to a list, read up on lists here - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

The current code that you have uploaded will display a table. To change it to lists, use the corresponding ul and li tags.

Comment: please, check the picture below code. I would like to display every tooltip at the same place. not everyone on a new row like it is now.

Answer (score 0):

for this time im done, i have to check it on other devices but... this is runs as I wanted to...

```
            while ($rowshowvarianty = mysqli_fetch_array($resultshowvarianty)) {
                echo '<tr id="line" class="line">
                        <td style="line-height: 25px; ">
                            <span style="width:250px;  background: #e74c3c;color: white;border-radius: 50%;    padding: 0px 7.5px;">
                                ?
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="    font-size: 13px;    width: 100%; ">
                            <a style="text-decoration: none;    color: #232323;"  href="?step=3&cil=' . $_GET['cil'] . '&plan=' . $rowshowvarianty['id'] . '">' . $rowshowvarianty['nazev'] . '</a>
                        </td>';
                $vs='width:400px; margin-left: -400px; position: absolute; top:' .-($nsb*28) . 'px;';
                $nsb++;
                echo '
                        <td style="' . $vs . '">
                        <span class="hiddentooltip" id="' . $rowshowvarianty['id'] . '">
                            ' . $rowshowvarianty['pruvodce'] . '
                        </span>
                      </td>
                     </tr>';
            }
```